# node mysql strip backticks or single quote

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) as mysql connector, most of the value within the variables are sent by user and so I have use placeholder to prevent sql injection. In the code below "req.params.TableName" and "req.params.order" is sent by user, the table and order variable values are entered from the front-end the value will be as as following.

**Values within variables will be:**

```
req.params.TableName = "officers"
req.params.order = asc OR desc
```

**Query:**

```
var table = [req.params.TableName, req.body.order];
var query = 'SELECT `officer_id` FROM ?? ORDER BY officer_id ??';
fullquery = mysql.format(query, table);
```

**Problem:**

The above code generates following query, which give me a syntax error because of backticks around ASC, how do i remove these backticks ? thanks

```
SELECT `officer_id` FROM `officers` ORDER BY officer_id `ASC`;
```

Comment: how did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Mysql Node is working exactly but i will give you a example.

```
req.params.TableName = 'officers';
req.params.order = asc || desc;

//Insert statement
var newOrder = encodeOrder({
    name: "'awesome'"
    price: 1000
  })

var query = "INSERT into orders values ??, ??";
fullquery = mysql.format(query, [newOrder.name, newOrder.price]);

//Like statement
var query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.name LIKE ?";
fullquery = mysql.format(query, [encodeURIComponent(order.name)]);

//DONT KNOW HOW TO EXECUTE >.<
var result = [{name: "\'awesome\'", price: 1000}]

for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
  result[index] = decodeOrder(result[index]);
}

//Result is now
// [{name: 'awesome', price: 1000});

//Can be reused for several objects ofcourse
function decodeOrder(order) {
    var result = {};

  //My expectation is that order is a object.
  Object.keys(order).forEach(function (key) {
    result[key] = decodeURIComponent(order[key])
  }

  return result;
}

//Can be reused for several objects ofcourse
function encodeOrder(order) {
  var result = {};

  //My expectation is that order is a object.
  Object.keys(order).forEach(function (key) {
    result[key] = encodeURIComponent(order[key])
  }

  return result;
}
```

This is out of my head. So don't know if this execute but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: actually i found another solution, I made my own module to strip every thing except alphnumberics, I'll upload it with doucmentation on github and npm then you can check it you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
req.params.TableName = 'officers';
req.params.order = asc || desc;

var table = [req.params.TableName, req.body.order];
var query = "SELECT `officer_id` FROM ?? ORDER BY officer_id ??";
fullquery = mysql.format(query, table);
```

Comment: how is this going to strip the backticks ?? please read my question

Comment: i added these two line just to understand what the values of variable can be

Comment: req.params.TableName = "officers"
req.params.order = asc OR desc

Comment: the values cannot be assigned manually the values will be coming from the front-end thats why i had to escape them first and then add them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

just need to use

```
.replace(/['`"/\]/g, "")
```

I will remove every special character from the string within the brackets.

Comment: Nice that that solved your issue. The only needle here is that for example if you have a string with "doesn't" for example it will be doesnt ;). So be aware that if you are trying a like with doesn't it will probably not find it

Comment: yeah i guess I'll have to live with that because if can either allow it or disallow it. I cannot do both at the same time, Thanks anyways

Comment: What you also could do but that cost more effort is EncodeURIComponent when inserting it in the database. If you do so be aware that all queries your are making to the database should also be EncodeURIComponent. If you are selecting data from database you could use DecodeURIComponent to not have weird characters in your result.

Comment: that awesome man i didn't knew this. can you give me an example how to deploy this using node mysql